# Как правильно сделать версионирование сборок VisualStudio C# + TeamCity

Tags: c#, teamcity, assembly, версионность, версионирование

У нас есть проект, в который потребовалось добавить версионирование.
Для проекта уже настроен сервер сборок TeamCity.
Почитав руководства в интернете я не совсем осознал, как правильно соединить версионирование библиотек Visual Studio с версионированием сборок TeamCity.
Может ли кто подсказать, как организовать самый простой способ версионирования, удовлетворяющий следующим запросам:
1) Версия библиотеки, которую мы не меняли, не изменялась при билдах и сборках в тимсити.
2) Можно было легко сопоставить - какие версии библиотек внутри конкретной сборки находятся.
3) не совсем понятно, должна ли версия сборки тимсити быть такой же, как самая большая версия библиотек visual studio ?

Comment: 1) Никому не должно быть интересно, какая там версия сборки в Visual Studio у программиста 2) Номера версий должен проставлять только билд сервер, и он сам увеличивает номер билда на каждый билд. При выпуске новой мажорной версии, номер версии увеличивается вручную на билд сервере- тимсити.

Comment: Мне нужно что бы в свойствах .dll была показана версия и я мог определить функционал, который присутствует (или отсутствует) в текущей версии. Плюс к этому эта версии должна соответствовать версии спринта в Redmine. Если увеличить мажорную версию в ТимСити, он в свойствах библиотеки .dll так же поменяет версию ?

Comment: У вас должен быть один источник версии для сборки - я вам предложил сделать жтим источником тимсити. В тимсити можно  настроить шаг, где он будет [патчить сборки](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/AssemblyInfo+Patcher) и [ставить там версию](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7258718/312041), которая указана в тимсити. Таки образом, если вы измените версию в тимсити и билд конфигурации ваши настроены верно, то все новые билды будут уже  с новой версией выходить.

Comment: По поводу Redmine - он отношения к процессу билда не имеет, потому там вы планируете и ставите номера ваших спринтов/версий вручную

Comment: Хорошо, а если делать источником версии ТимСити, то в проекте мне в AssemblyInfo вобще все-равно что писать ? Это будет игнорироваться ?

Comment: `то в проекте мне в AssemblyInfo вобще все-равно что писать?` - Да